# TransactionScope in business or data/repository class?

Tags: c#, database, transaction

What is the best place to use TransactionScope class? Is it in the business logic or data/repository classes?

Example if used in business logic class:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    Repository.DoSomething();
    Repository.DoSomethingMore();
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Example if used in data/repository class:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    "INSERT INTO ..."  // some actual SQL
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: I *strongly* advocate not using the implicit `TransactionScope` at all. It makes it too easy to unwittingly pull things into a transaction that you don't intend. In the best case, this leads to larger than necessary transactions, in the worst case it leads to failures due to deadlock or transactions becoming distributed when you haven't enabled (nor want) distributed transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single transaction represent a single consistent operation within your system. Where you initiate a transaction depends solely on your business needs.

A typical scenario is bank transfer, where you MUST ensure that funds have been withdrawn from account A and credited to account B. In this case, before doing any database operation the withdrawal/credit would be wrapped in a transaction to make the operation fully complete.

If your business operation requires multiple changes to a database and it's important that either all operations or none goes through then initiating a transaction at the business layer is what you want.

For simple queries like a single insert (your second example) you do not need to run a transaction because such operations guarantee operation safety by default.

Answer (score 2):

One of the benefits to transaction scope as opposed to a transaction is that you can use it without reference to the connection.

This allows you to potentially use it outside of the data layer so the business logic can decide whether two or more data operations should be part of the same transaction or not.

However, having said that TransactionScope is still dependent on the connection object supporting it. So using it outside of the DAL introduces this hidden dependency. Which is far from ideal.

My personal approach is to keep its use in the Repository class where generic private methods such as InsertMyObject(connection con) assume a transaction may be in scope and specific public methods such as UpdateMyObjectsByDate() create the transactions and call the private methods as required.

You can argue that the specific methods overlap to some extent with business logic. But thats a somewhat 'soft' problem rather than a 'hard', you actually have a dependency I can point at, problem